# sdk manager cannot update to 24.0.2

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Eclipse runs fine and all sdk packages have updated. 
the following updates will cannot update.
**Android SDK Platform 4.1.2
Revision 4
Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2**

The following message is what I receive.

> Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2 Failed to rename
>   directory C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools to C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01. [find_lock]
>   Directory locked by cmd.exe;java.exe Downloading SDK Platform Android
>   4.1.2, API 16, revision 4 Installing SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4 Failed to rename directory C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16 to C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformPackage.old01. [find_lock]
>   Directory locked by eclipse.exe Done. Nothing was installed.

Answer (score 0):

delete the contents of the `temp` directory in the `SDK` installation folder. 
(`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\`)